# How to include @ symbol inside Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using ASP.NET MVC, and in one of the Razor view I have to include the script using CDN

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@process"></script>
```

I am getting the following error

> CS0103: The name 'process' does not exist in the current context

I tried using @@ instead of @, but it did not work.

Comment: I see `proCess` and `proGRess`. Maybe thats the issue here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved like this.

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@('@')process"></script>
```

Comment: Helped a lot, thanks. I think you should accept this answer/